# Bold the first line of strings that are assigned to y-axis text in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Considering the followinf dataframes as an example

```
DF1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c("a", "b", "c"))
DF2 <- data.frame(Y = paste0("this is the first line thats bold ", DF1$A, "\n",
                            "this is the second line thats plain ", DF1$B),
                 X = structure(c(18903, 18965, 19081), class = "Date"))
```

`DF2` looks like this:

```
> DF2
                                                                           Y          X
1 this is the first line thats bold 1\nthis is the second line thats plain a 2021-10-03
2 this is the first line thats bold 2\nthis is the second line thats plain b 2021-12-04
3 this is the first line thats bold 3\nthis is the second line thats plain c 2022-03-30
```

Now if I create a simple scatter plot of this data:

```
ggplot(DF2, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

How can I make the first line of the y-axis text bold? so I want the `this is the first line thats bold 1(2,3)` be bold and the `this is the second line thats plain A(B,C)` to remain plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggtext` package allows to format axis text as Markdown:

```r
library(ggtext)
library(tidyverse)

DF1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c("a", "b", "c"))
DF2 <- data.frame(
  Y = paste0(
    "this is the first line thats bold ", DF1$A, "\n",
    "this is the second line thats plain ", DF1$B
  ),
  X = structure(c(18903, 18965, 19081), class = "Date")
)


DF2 %>%
  mutate(Y = Y %>% str_replace("^", "**") %>% str_replace("\n", "**\n\n")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Nice answer +1 ! Do you know why we need two `\n` (`"**\n\n"`) for it to work?

Comment: In Markdown, a whole new line is the line break. A single `\n` will be ignored and put in the same paragraph.

Comment: Then shall we use `str_replace("\n", "**<br>"))` instead? Seems like this would also remove the extra space between the two lines

Comment: Yes, one can also use HTML tags here. This is required e.g. for coloring.

Comment: Thank you @danlooo. can you please explain why the `str_replace("^", "**")` is necessary?

Comment: `**` is markdown syntax for bold text. `^` is the regular expression for the start of the character string